# Elder Scroll Online Addon

Tags: lua, add-on

This is my first time working with `Lua`, but not with programming. I have experience in Java, Action Script, and HTML. I am trying to create an `addon` for `Elder Scroll Online`. I managed to find the `ESO API` at the following link:

http://wiki.esoui.com/API#Player_Escorting

I am trying to make a function that returns a count of how many items each guild member has deposited in the bank. The code I have so far is as follows

```
function members()
    for i=0, GetNumGuildEvents(3, GUILD_EVENT_BANKITEM_ADDED)
    do
        GetGuildEventInfo(3, GUILD_EVENT_BANKITEM_ADDED, i)
    end
```

I am having trouble referencing the character making the specific deposit. Once I am able to do that I foresee making a linked list storing character names and an `integer/double` counter for the number of items deposited. If anyone has an idea of how to reference the character for a given deposit it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the game to test and the API documentation is sparse, so what follows are educated guesses/tips/hints (I know Lua well and programmed WoW for years).

Lua supports multiple assignment and functions can return multiple values:

```
    function foo() 
        return 1, "two", print 
    end
    local a, b, c = foo()
    c(a,b) -- output: 1, "two"
```

GetGuildEventInfo says it returns the following:

```
eventType, secsSinceEvent, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5
```

Given that this function applies to multiple guild event types, I would expect param1 through param5 are specific to the particular event you're querying. Just print them out and see what you get. If you have a `print` function available that works something like Lua's standard print function (i.e. accepts multiple arguments and prints them all), you can simple write:

```
    print(GetGuildEventInfo(3,GUILD_EVENT_BANKITEM_ADDED,i))
```

To print all its return values.

If you don't have a `print`, you should write one. I see the function [`LogChatText`](http://wiki.esoui.com/API#Chat) which looks suspiciously like something that would write text to your chat window. If so, you can write a Lua-esque print function like this:

```
function print(...)
    LogChatText(table.concat({...}, ' '))
end
```

If you find from your experimentation that, say, param1 is the name of the player making the deposit, you can write:

```
    local eventType, secsSinceEvent, playerName = GetGuildEventInfo(3,GUILD_EVENT_BANKITEM_ADDED, i)
```

> I foresee making a linked list storing character names and an integer/double counter for the number of items deposited.

You wouldn't want to do that with a linked list (not in Lua, Java nor ActionScript). Lua is practically built on hashtables (aka 'tables'), which in Lua are very powerful and generalized, capable of using any type as either key or value.

```
local playerEvents = {} -- this creates a table
playerEvents["The Dude"] = 0 -- this associates the string "The Dude" with the value 0
print(playerEvents["The Dude"]) -- retrieve the value associated with the string "The Dude"
playerEvents["The Dude"] = playerEvents["The Dude"] + 1 -- this adds 1 to whatever was previous associated with The Dude
```

If you index a table with a key which hasn't been written to, you'll get back `nil`. You can use this to determine if you've created an entry for a player yet.

We're going to pretend that param1 contains the player name. Fix this when you find out where it's actually located:

```
local itemsAdded = {}
function members() 
    for i=0, GetNumGuildEvents(3, GUILD_EVENT_BANKITEM_ADDED ) do
        local eventType, secsSinceEvent, playerName = GetGuildEventInfo(3, GUILD_EVENT_BANKITEM_ADDED, i)
        itemsAdded[playerName] = (itemsAdded[playerName] or 0) + 1
    end
end
```

`itemsAdded` now contains the number of items added by each player. To print them out:

```
for name, count in pairs(itemsAdded) do
    print(string.format("Player %s has added %d items to the bank.", name, count))
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will work on implementing this and testing it out. To test it i should export it ant install it to the game and see what happens right?